# Python: specific value in a named tuple of a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples, namedtuple

I was wondering if it is possible to print a value that is inside a list of lists of tuples if you already know the indexes path.

```
1. List[i][j]
2.   list2[x][y]
3.      list3[z][w]
4.         etc.
```

I would like to do something like this:

`str(  list[i][0 [0][2 [0][0]]  )`

To get the value at indexes 0,0 in the tuple at indexes 0,2 of a list at indexes i,0 of the main list.

**Edit:**
Sorry, I'm learning. Console returns this:

```
    [Record(items=set({'item1','item2'}),
            id=6439,
            stats=[OrderedStatistic(items_b=set({'item2'}),
                                    items_a=set({'item1'}),
                                    row=123,
                                    col=321)]),
     Record(...
```

I'm looking for the "row" value. I didn't know it had a name, it wasn't showed in my viewer.

**Edit 2:**

Improvement. It works, but I'm using a temporary variable because  `oldList[0].stats[0].row` returns a `'stats' object has no attribute row`.

```
for i in range(0, len(oldList)):
    tmpList = oldList[i][2]
    newList.append('ID:\t' + str(oldList[i][1])+ '\nROW:\t' + str(tmpList[0][2])
```

or

```
for i in range(0, len(oldList)):
    tmpList = oldList[i][2]
    newList.append('ID:\t' + str(oldList[i][1])+ '\nROW:\t' + str(tmpList[0].row)
```

Comment: Please add example input tuple and desired output.

Comment: If indexing the object results in a sequence, just index that as well.

Comment: Short answer is yes. Could you provide sample data (even fake), which is correctly structured?

Comment: @dawg Sorry, I don't know what you mean with input tuple or desired output.

Comment: @Mika72 Added a line, is it helping?

Comment: Are those [named tuples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) you have there?

Comment: Yes! I didn't know they had names, my Spyder viewer uses index as names and I assumed they were nameless.

Comment: @dawg Thank you! I edited my post. Is it readable now?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax in this case would be as follows:

```
print(lst[i][0][0][2][0][0])
```

That nested structure is more than just a list of lists of tuples though. If that were the case, then the following minimal example list could have the 'a' referenced with a simple `lst[0][0][0]`:

```
lst = [[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e', 'f')]]
```

Comment: Thank you Brandon. 
`lst = [[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', ('e1' , 'e2'), 'f')]]`
It should look like this, with e2 as the value I'm looking for.
I also updated my original post with a sample.

Comment: In that case, you would want `lst[0][1][1][1]`.

Comment: Yes, I already tried but it returns a `TypeError "set" object does not support indexing`
That was my first attempt. I made a test on an array and it works. I'm probably misreading the lists.

Comment: For your example, try `lst[0].stats[0].row`.

Comment: It doesn't work, but you helped me a lot! I edited my post to make it a bit more readable.

Answer (score 0):

In a simple way for the `lst = [[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', ('e1' , 'e2'), 'f')]]` example you can use `lst[0][1][1][1]` to reach `e2`, but I imagine that you have the indexes in an array like `ind_array`. in this case you may have to do something like this:

```
ind_array = [0, 1, 1, 1]
desired_value = lst
for i in o :
    try:
        desired_value = desired_value[i]
     except IndexError:
         print('index not found.')
         break
 print(desired_value)
```

Let me know if you have problem with answer or you will have the indexes differently.